# Bandwidth and Speed monitoring software

Tags: networking, monitoring, bandwidth, internet

I am looking to get some advice on what you guys think would be a good fit for my requirements.

My goal is to find software which would monitor internet speed (UP/DOWN), ping times and more(possibly) then send it to a remote DB where I could access this information and possibly have it displayed on a webpage (the webpage part is not a requirement, but a "nice to have" feature).

I plant to deploy this across multiple offices in order to track their line quality.

Would anyone know of a good software for achieving this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Free:** You should use [ntop](http://www.ntop.org/products/ntop/) for this requirement

[image: line_graph]
[image: pie_graph]

**Commercial:** Use Cisco's [Netflow](http://www.cisco.com/go/netflow) and [IP SLA](http://www.cisco.com/go/ipsla)

Comment: You're most welcome... good luck with your project

Answer (score 1):

+1 for Mike's recommendation. I completely agree that ntop is a great tool for fairly detailed network analysis. You can see a lot of the traffic going across your network and it breaks it down very well. Along with that, it looks like some of the items you want are more Nagios and Cacti related.

[Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) is going to give you more generic monitoring and you can easily get your ping times a long with a lot of other system/link up/down notices with this.

[Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/) is going to do a great job of graphing the overall bandwidth usage of various interfaces on your switches and routers. It will give you a very clear graphical representation of overall speed.